# Disable scrollbar globally, but enable on specific element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to disable css scrollbar on site globally, but enable on specific element, such as custom select menu ?

Following code simply display blank whitespace on `.select` element

And I have tried different !important options as well

```
body, html
  ::-webkit-scrollbar
    display: none
    -webkit-appearance: none
  ::scrollbar
    display: none

  div.select::-webkit-scrollbar
    display: block !important
    opacity: 1 !important
    width: 10px
    // -webkit-appearance: block
  div.select::scrollbar
    display: block !important
    opacity: 1 !important
    width: 10px
```

Codepen http://codepen.io/dpmango/pen/gLNpre

Comment: How about a [mcve]

Comment: You are right, http://codepen.io/dpmango/pen/gLNpre

Comment: what about just body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: This come at the top `*::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0;height:0}` and this comes after `ElementWithScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {width:20px;height:20}` - Note that the scroll bar will still show on FF / IE / O / any other none webkit browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following css to disable scrollbar:

```
    html,body{
       overflow:hidden;
   }
```

but for select item you can use:

```
 .select{
   overflow:auto;
  }
```