# How to make global scrollbar apply to only one element

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, frontend

I have a beautiful dashboard made with Bootstrap, with an alerts list on the right side. This alerts list is the only thing that scrolls, and I really want to apply the scrolling of the page to just this element.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334968/disable-scrollbar-globally-but-enable-on-specific-element#41335194) with someone asking something similar a few months ago, but the solution given was just to disable the page scrollbar and enable a scrollbar for the element. What I'm looking to do is keep the page scrollbar, but make it scroll only the one element.

Solutions I've Tried:

- Position fixed - Completely and irrevocably breaks Bootstrap
- Whole page position fixed and `window.scrollTo()` for element - Ugly and inconsistent

Is there a good way of making the page scrollbar apply to one specific element, where CSS `position: fixed` can't be used on the element without breaking the page?

Comment: unless you use body as the element in my below answer the the page scrollbar stays!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Manos](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) library! download it from [here](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/archive/master.zip)
Instructions from site:

## HTML

Include `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css` in the head tag your HTML document (more info)

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
```

Include jQuery library (if your project doesn’t use it already) and jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js in the head tag or at the very bottom of your document, just before the closing body tag

```
<script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

## CSS

The element(s) you want to add scrollbar(s) should have the typical CSS properties of an overflowed block which are a height (or max-height) value, an overflow value of auto (or hidden) and content long enough to require scrolling. For horizontal scrollbar, the element should have a width (or max-width) value set.

If you prefer to set your element’s height/width via javascript, you can use  the setHeight/setWidth option parameters.

## Initialization

## Initialize via javascript

After files inclusion, call `mCustomScrollbar` function on the element selector you want to add the scrollbar(s)

```
 <script>
    (function($){
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

## Initialize via HTML

Add the class `mCustomScrollbar` to any element you want to add custom scrollbar(s) with default options. Optionally, set its axis via the HTML data attribute data-mcs-axis (e.g. "x" for horizontal and "y" for vertical) and its theme via data-mcs-theme. For example:

```
<div class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
  <!-- your content -->
</div>
```

## Basic configuration & option parameters

## axis

By default, the script applies a vertical scrollbar. To add a horizontal or 2-axis scrollbars, invoke mCustomScrollbar function with the axis option set to "x" or "yx" respectively

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
axis:"x" // horizontal scrollbar
});
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
axis:"yx" // vertical and horizontal scrollbar
});
```

## theme

To quickly change the appearance of the scrollbar, set the theme option  parameter to any of the ready-to-use themes available in    `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css`, for example:

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
theme:"dark"
});
```